# JavaFX textfield settext não funciona

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Tenho uma tela de cadastro, usando `FXML`, e quero reutilizar essa tela para o botão alterar.

Mas quando faço:

```
txtNome.setText("ola");
System.out.println(txtNome.getText());
```

Abre a tela de cadastro, com o campo `Nome` em branco, no console retorna `"ola"` e não retorna nenhum erro.

Código em que abre a tela de cadastro:

```java
public void newPage(String path){

        try {
            Stage stage;
            Parent root;
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
            root = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            txtNome = new TextField();
            txtNome.setText("ola");
            System.out.println(txtNome.getText());
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 900));
            stage.showAndWait();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom como você não deu mais detalhes do seu código, imagino que você quer que ao clicar no botão alterar seja aberta uma tela em modal já com informações como por exemplo: nome de usuário?

se sim, segue um código:

```
    public void newPage(String path) {

    try {

        FXMLLoader root = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        ControllerModal controllerModal = new ControllerModal("teste texto");
        root.setController(controllerModal);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root.load());

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.showAndWait();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Classe ControllerModal:**

```
public class ControllerModal implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Label texto;

private String testeTexto;

public ControllerModal(String testeTexto) {
    this.testeTexto = testeTexto;
}


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    texto.setText(testeTexto);
}}
```

**Explicação:**

Bom, com esse código vai ser necessário criar uma nova classe controladora para esse modal, assim seguindo o padrão MVC (dessa maneira você não deve reutilizar o mesmo FXML).

Se não foi isso o que querias, deixe mais detalhes.